# Ajax DELETE Query Returning Unexpected Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongoose

My delete controller and AJAX Query are passing unexpected results in data.

I have the following in my AJAX request:

`var endpoint = '/api/places/'+$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: endpoint,
      dataType:"json", 
      data: $(this).serializeArray(),
      success: deletePlace,
      error: handleError
    });`

where endpoint is a valid URL and the same URL in my controller, shown here:

`app.delete('/api/places/:id', function deletePlace(req, res) {
      // remove place
      db.Place.remove({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, removePlace){
        if (err) { throw (err) };
        res.json(removePlace);
      });`

The data passed into deletePlace is "Object {ok: 1, n: 1}" when I am expecting it to be the JSON of the removed Place. Please excuse my novice but I have been wracking my brain on this. Have searched so many posts on here and still can't find the answer.

Comment: `$(this).serializeArray()` should probably be `$(this).serialize()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `.remove` will not return deleted document.

So You've to use `.findByIdAndRemove` method.

Please read api carefully: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove

Here is the fix:

```
app.delete('/api/places/:id', function deletePlace(req, res) {
  // remove place
  db
    .Place
    .findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, 
      function(error, deletedDocument) {
        if (error) {
          return 
            res
              .status(500)
              .send({
                success: false, 
                error: error, 
                data: {}
              });
        }

        res
          .send({
            success: true, 
            data: deletedDocument
          });
      });
});
```